# R: Packge "broom" - function "process_rq()" not found

Tags: r

I am trying to process an rqs-object with the process_rq function, however after installing and also attaching the broom package. I get the following error:

```
Error in process_rq(qr.model.summary.cont, se.type = "boot", conf.int = FALSE,  : 
  could not find function "process_rq"
```

Here is my session info:

```
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.6

other attached packages:
[1] broom_0.4.3
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I checked this with ?process_rq and it gives me: process_rq {broom}

Comment: `broom:::process_rq`, you should see [this article on double and triple colon operators](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/ns-dblcolon.html) for more details

Comment: Taking a look at the [source code](https://github.com/tidyverse/broom/blob/defdf42737e06b22f802b7c24df5d82d4a528ac1/R/rq_tidiers.R#L232) it looks like `process_rq` is an internal helper function and thus not exported

Comment: Perfekt, thank you!